# How to determine the window index position of programs int he desktop?

Tags: applescript

For example if I want to know what is window behind the front/active window, how do I grab it from the window properties?

Answer (score 1):

Inside an application:

```
tell application (path to frontmost application as text)
    item 2 of (windows whose visible is true)
end tell
```

But AFAIK there's no way to do it if the second window is in another application. (Besides resorting to hacks like emulating the shortcut used for *Move focus to active or next window*.)